# Фильтрация массива объектов по массиву строк

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как вернуть значения из массива объектов, применяя фильтры?

У меня есть массив объектов `arrayOfObjects`:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{
    zone: { country: "Cuba" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: "1",
        name: 'apple',
        filter: 'fresh',
    }
}, {
    zone: { country: "France" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: "2",
        name: 'orange',
        filter: 'old',
    }
}, {
    zone: { country: "Poland" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: '3',
        name: 'melon',
        filter: 'withered',
    }
}, {
    zone: { country: "Spain" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: "4",
        name: 'grapes',
        filter: 'stale',
    }
}]
```

Есть значения для фильтрации:

```js
let filter = ['fresh', 'stale']
```

В итоге должно получиться так:

```js
let newArrayOfObjects =  [{
    zone: { country: "Cuba" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: "1",
        name: 'apple',
        filter: 'fresh',
    }
}, {
    zone: { country: "Spain" },
    equipment:
    {
        _id: "4",
        name: 'grapes',
        filter: 'stale',
    }
}];
```

Не получается нормальный фильтр написать, вот пример моего кода:

```js
newArrayOfObjects  = arrayOfObjects.filter(function (currentItem) {
    if (_.isMatch(currentItem.equipment, filter)) {
        return true
    }
})
```

Comment: Я заметил, что у вас нет ни одного принятого ответа.  Ответ, который вы считаете лучшим, надо отмечать как верный, нажав галочку.

Comment: Хорошее замечание, я принимаю Ваш ответ, спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гибкое решение:

```
let newArrayOfObjects = filterHelper.call(arrayOfObjects, 
  'equipment.filter', ['fresh' , 'stale']
); 

function filterHelper(propPath, values) {
  const list = Object.fromEntries(values.map(v => [v, true])), 
        path = propPath.split('.');
  const propValOf = obj => path.reduce((r, p) => r[p], obj); 
  return this.filter(o => propValOf(o) in list); 
}
```

Comment: Гибкость конечно не бесплатна: вызовы `propValOf` будут замедлять, но хз как оптимальнее реализовать обход свойств по строковому пути без использования `eval` (который тут никак нельзя, опасно).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Очень интересное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```js
const filter = ['fresh', 'stale'];
const filterSet = new Set(filter);
const filtered = arrayOfObjects.filter(e => filterSet.has(e.equipment.filter));
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую...